# Как в сериализаторе отформатировать данные REST FRAMEWORK

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Возможно ли при сериализации модели изменить данные?

Сериализатор

```
class SpecializationsPageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SpecializationsPage
        fields = ['url_path']
```

в поле url_path значение `/home/some-page/some-page/...`

нужно чтобы поле  url_path выдавало значение `/some-page/some-page/...` , конкретнее удаляло первое слово и первую косую черту `/home`